# Styled components: cannot find name 'ref' when trying to pass a ref

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I'm trying to pass a ref to be read inside of `emotion` component (similar to `styled-components)`

But receving the error `Cannot find name 'ref'`

What should I do in order to be able to access the ref inside the emotion component?

```
const Label = styled('p')<{ ref: React.MutableRefObject<null> }>({
  fontsize: ref.current...,
});

export const NodeDisplayer = ({ data }) => {
  const size = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Label  ref={size} id="title">
        
      </Label>
    </>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a reference to a component function, because it does not exist in the DOM. You need to reference the HTML element, which you might as well do in the child. And since the ref will not be populated until *after* the component has rendered, you need to use `useEffect` to get the referenced node.

```js
function Label() {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);
  const [style, setStyle] = useState<CSSProperties>({});
  useEffect(() => setStyle({ fontSize: ref.current.clientWidth + 'px' }), []);

  return (
    <p ref={ref} style={style}>
      Hi
    </p>
  );
}

export const NodeDisplayer = () => <Label></Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Why would a component need to access its own DOM node to determine its styling? I doubt it will work properly.

But to answer your question, the `ref` prop is special in React so it isn't accessible in the props, but nothing prevents you from also adding it as a different prop:

```js
<Label ref={size} myRef={size} id="title">
```

Then you should be able to access `myRef`.

Comment: I would like to access its own DOM to get the width of the element and calculate font size (or margins) based on it. I tried your solution with myRef, but getting the exact same error, 'cannot find name 'myRef'.. thanks in advance